# Delete item from list that contains specific substring?

Tags: kotlin

I've got this mutable list:

```
val array: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("laptop on floor", "man is thomas")
```

How do I remove the element that contains `flo`? In my case, I want to have the  element `laptop on floor` removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
array.removeAll { item -> item.contains("flo") }
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use [removeAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html) to modify the existing list, or [filterNot](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html) to create a copy

There are two ways to do this, depending on whether you want to change the list you already have, or create a new list.

### `filterNot`

The more 'Kotlin' way to do this is to treat the original list as immutable, and create a copy with your changes. Treating collections as immutable helps avoid bugs and make the program easier to follow.

```kotlin
val list = listOf("laptop on floor", "man is thomas")
val newList = list.filterNot { "flo" in it }
```

After this operation, the original `list` still contains both items. The
`newList` copy only contains `"man is thomas"`.

### `removeAll`

If you need to modify the existing list, you can use `removeAll` to remove the elements you don't want.

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf("laptop on floor", "man is thomas")
list.removeAll { "flo" in it }
```

After this operation, you still have just the one list, and it only contains `"man is thomas"`.